# Why do only points appear when I load shapefiles into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, mapping

I was sent files in these formats : .cpg, .dbf, .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .shp, and .shx.
I tried importing the zipped file containing all of them using Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer and selecting the file thinking a complete map would appear, but only points appear.

Clearly I am a total newbie with QGIS so I don't know if this is normal or if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Shapefiles only contain a single type of vector data among point, line and polygon. What data was the provider supposed to send you?

Comment: A single shapefile is a mix of different files.  You were sent a single point shapefile.  See here for some technical information on shapefiles.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: Also all the file are part of the same shapefile (unless you have several of each type) see this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile to have an explanation of what they are

Answer (score 3):

It is normal: you are apparently importing, in the QGIS project map, a layer containing features with associated point geometries.

Please read the basic GIS documentation an to the QGIS documentation which is available at https://qgis.org/en/docs/index.html, beginning in particular with the "gentle introduction in GIS" and the "QGIS Training manual" docs.